# Android Studio Emulator disappears after Bumblebee update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I recently updated my Android Studio to "Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1" and now I have this weird bug where my emulator would disappear randomly. It works fine for sometime but would randomly disappear. In the device manager it shows that emulator is running but in the emulator tab it shows "No emulator is currently running"
As you can see from the screenshot attached green dot in the device manager that means "Emulator is running", whereas it isn't. The only way to get back emulator is to "cold reboot it" from the device manager. Anyone else facing the same bug? Any suggestions as to where to look trying to debug this. I've tried deleting and installing emulator again but the issue persisted.[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Had exactly the same issue on BumbleBee and the only way that I found to go about this, was to use a detached emulator in a separate window.

To run the emulator in a separate window go to **File** > **Settings** > **Tools** > **Emulator** (On Mac -> *Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator ) and deselect `Launch in a tool window`.

This way the emulator will always be there.

Comment: This works, even for "Always on Top" functionality.

Comment: Are there any news about this "feature" becoming fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Double press shift , the way we do to find project files in android studio , and type Emulator, click on the first option that shows up and you have your emulator!
[image]

Comment: it also works for Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 1):

I also had random emulator crashes, everything would work for a short while, but then the emulator would just disappear. There's still an `emulator.exe` running in the task manager, but no way to recover and the .lock file couldn't be removed.

Even just starting the emulator and swiping the home screen left and right or opening the apps drawer would cause the emulator to stop working properly.

What worked for me was to always start Android Studio as "Run as administrator". So right click on the startmenu shortcut and select Run as administrator.

[image]

As with many Android Studio issues, I'm not sure what the actual reason was but this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updated Android studio to version BumbleBee| 2021.1.1 Patch 2.
I reInstalled My Intel acceleration to the latest version from the below link:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
finally, my problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. As I later discovered the emulator was somehow resized (possibly by a kid) to the smallest posssible size and become almost invisible on the screen:

[[image: Almost invisible1]

[image: After I found it]